# How to do string replacement for specified number of times using linux commands?

Tags: awk, sed

I am using the following sed command to replace a string

```
sed -i "s|find string|replace string|g" inputfile
```

But it will replace all the Occurrences. (I think `g` is for `Global` replacement)

How can i do the string replacement for only specified number times i.e, 10 times or 15 times using **sed** or **grep** or **awk**..?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/394282/sed-perform-only-first-nth-matched-replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
 perl -pe '$i++ while($i < 10 && s/pattern/replace/)' input
```

In awk:

```
 awk '{ while( i< c && sub( "pattern", "replace" )) i+=1}1' c=10 input
```

Comment: `-p` causes perl to loop over its input and print each line, and `-e` simply specifies the code to run (the next argument after `-e`).

Comment: `i+=1` is the same as `i++`

Comment: @jotne `i++` is an expression, but `i+=1` is a statement.  As a side-effect, `i++` increments `i`, so in that sense they are semantically similar, but they evaluate differently when used on the RHS of an assignment.  I find it much more readable to use `i+=1` as it makes the intent clear.

Answer (score 1):

pur sed but better not to use sed for such a problem, prefer a awk (or perl)

```
sed -n -e '1h;1!H
$ {s/.*//;x
   t loop
:loop
   s|find string|replace string|
   t occur
   b print
:occur
   x
   s/$/o/
   t count
:count
   s/o\{10\}/&/
   x
   t print
   b loop
:print
   p
   }' YourFile
```

10 in `s/o\{10\}/&/` is the number of occurence wanted. use of the `s//;t label` as if/goto. without 'else', lot of `s//;t`.

First, the whole file need to be loaded in working buffer (sed work per line by default). Also, it use the secondary buffer as counter.

Comment: Nice technique. But it is not necessary to read the entire file into the temporary buffer: `sed ':loop; x; s/o\{10\}/&/; x; t; s/pattern/replace/; t count; b; :count; x; s/^/o/; x; t loop;'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other `awk` version.

```
awk 'c && sub("pattern","replace") {c--}1' c=2 file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more readable `awk` version:

```
awk '{for(i=0; i<15; i++) sub("pattern", "replacement"); print $0}' file
```